# FB Cookies are cached in Facebook App

Tags: facebook-graph-api, coldfusion, session-cookies, application.cfc

I'm using the affinitiz Facebook API for ColdFusion https://github.com/affinitiz/facebook-cf-sdk  to develop a Facebook App and I'm having real troubles with the events after authentication.

The API scrapes the app cookie just fine and I get logged in, but only with the help of an extra call to the template, a reload if you will. After the reload everything falls in place and I am able to get the user session with access token.

I've placed the calls to the API in an Application.cfc in the OnRequest event.

So here is the weird thing, no matter how many calls to the API I make from ColdFusion, the only thing that will get me the newest App Cookie is by reloading the template (I do this with JavaScript as a workaround).

It is as if the App cookie is cached somehow and is only refreshed on reload, eventhough the user is authenticated.

To recap, the procedure is as follows:

1. OnRequest Event
2. API scrapes cookie
3. so we reload
4. OnRequest Event
5. API scrapes cookie
6. we have Facebook UID and access_token.

These are the session cookie settings in the Application.cfc.

```
<cfset THIS.SessionManagement = true />
<cfset THIS.SetClientCookies = true />
<cfset THIS.ClientManagement = true />
```

Thanks for your help!

The OnRequest code is quite extensive, but here goes:

```
    import facebook.sdk.FacebookApp;
    import facebook.sdk.FacebookGraphAPI;

    // Replace this with your appId and secret
    APP_ID = "zzz";
    SECRET_KEY = "zzz";
    API_KEY = "zzz";
    session.appID = APP_ID;
    session.apiKey = API_KEY;

    // Create facebookApp instance
    //this.utils.runTimer("facebookAuth-newfacebookApp","start");
    facebookApp = new FacebookApp(appId=APP_ID, secretKey=SECRET_KEY);
    //this.utils.runTimer("facebookAuth-newfacebookApp","stop");
    session.fbApp = facebookApp;

    // We may or may not have this data based on a URL or COOKIE based session.
    //
    // If we get a session here, it means we found a correctly signed session using
    // the Application Secret only Facebook and the Application know. We dont know
    // if it is still valid until we make an API call using the session. A session
    // can become invalid if it has already expired (should not be getting the
    // session back in this case) or if the user authenticated out of Facebook.

    //this.utils.runTimer("facebookAuth-getUserSession","start");
    userSession = facebookApp.getUserSession();


    //this.utils.runTimer("facebookAuth-getUserSession","stop");

    authenticated = false;
    if (structKeyExists(userSession, "uid")) {
        if(structKeyExists(session.fbUserSession,"uid")){
            if(userSession.uid NEQ session.fbUserSession.uid){
                // reset session variables;
            }
        }
        session.fbUserSession = userSession;
        try {
            facebookGraphAPI = new FacebookGraphAPI(userSession.access_token);
            session.fbGraphAPI = facebookGraphAPI;

            session.fbGraphAPI = facebookGraphAPI;

            if (NOT session.fbAuthenticated){
                session.fbAuthenticated = true;
                session.justLoggedIn = true;
            }
            session.fbLoginCounter = 3;
            authenticated = true;
        } catch (any exception) {
            // Ignore exception (OAuthInvalidTokenException), usually an invalid session
        } finally {

            facebookGraphAPI = new FacebookGraphAPI();

        }
    } else {

        facebookGraphAPI = new FacebookGraphAPI();
        session.fbUserSession = StructNew();
            //this.utils.runTimer("facebookAuth-FacebookGraphAPI-else","stop");
    }

    session.parameters = structNew();
    session.parameters["req_perms"] = "publish_stream, email";
```

I can then access the FB cookie through the session.

Comment: I suspect many people here are not familiar with the affinitiz Facebook API. How are you calling it?  Can you show your onRequest code? What does it return?

Comment: I've just fixed it. Calling the API from Application.cfc's onRequest event was the culprit. I was under the impression that onRequest was like adding code on top of all .cfm templates.

I added the calls to the exposed templates and everything works smoothly. Somehow the session cookies lag behind in the onRequest even such that they are only reset on refresh.

If anybody can shed any light on why this is I would be really happy :D (I will submit this as an answer as soon as my lurker timer is up)

Comment: I never use onRequest, so I don't know of any problems with it, but I have also never heard of any.  Does the code work if you put it in onRequestStart() instead?

Answer (score 1):

I'm curious about this section right here:

```
if(structKeyExists(session.fbUserSession,"uid")){
        if(userSession.uid NEQ session.fbUserSession.uid){
            // reset session variables;
        }
    }
    session.fbUserSession = userSession;
```

On the very first request is there any value in session.fbUserSession.uid? I would guess not. It looks like you are not setting that value  until the 3rd line after that.  Does that mean that whatever replaces //reset session variables will get called? And would that possibly cause you some problems?  I don't know what that code does, but it seems like, from what I am seeing that session.fbUserSession would not have a value in it for your check until at least the second request. Which means that the //reset session variables code would be run on the first request every time. Is that what you want?

Comment: It is scraped as soon as there is a cookie.

Answer (score 0):

I've just fixed it. Calling the API from Application.cfc's onRequest event was the culprit. I was under the impression that onRequest was like adding code on top of all .cfm templates.

I added the calls to the exposed templates and everything works smoothly. Somehow the session cookies lag behind in the onRequest even such that they are only reset on refresh.

If anybody can shed any light on why this is I would be really happy.